# In Expo, what is the difference between the app.json and app.config.json

Tags: expo

In the `Expo` documentation found [over here](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/) they talk about `app.json` and `app.config.js`, how the former is static and the latter is dynamic.  They very briefly mention `app.config.json` lower down:

> There are two different types of configs: static (app.config.json, app.json)

But they do not specify what the distinctions are between these two static configurations and which of them is preferable.

Can anyone explain the distinction, because the Expo documentation seems to be quite thin on explanations here.

Comment: Json files are static (all keys and values are specified beforehand and cannot change based on external factors such as Environment Variable). On the other hand, you can add logics in Js file to have different config depends on your build environment.

Comment: I understand the difference between static and dynamic, and why you would use a js file to specify a config that is based on your build environment. The question is why are there two types of static definitions: app.json and app.config.json. Why would you use one rather than the other? What is the difference between app.json and app.config.json?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the source code, it seems like there's no difference between either of it, they are both treated as static config file: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/33efd9c7bdc89dccfe8a77d06e6c3e4fd693adde/packages/%40expo/config/src/Config.ts#L222

(Only difference is `app.config.json` has higher precedence due to its order in the code, which is documented here: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/#configuration-resolution-rules)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code. From that it does seem that they are identical. I ended up having both in my project; I think because I started off using Expo Go and then later changed to using dev client.  As I recall, there was a tutorial that I was following that suggested to me that I should use app.config.json, stating that this was the preferable way to define the config. 

So I can just get rid of app.json in my project because it is being ignored anyway.

Comment: All of these are just "the app config" so you only need one @BruceHill.  I also believe I had Expo auto-generate two of them and one was being ignored leading to some strange issues with my data being ignored.  Now I know why.  Expo should warn if there are multiple config files present.  Source: "The app config (app.json, app.config.js, app.config.ts)" https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only difference is that in `app.config.json` you cannot calcualate variables, neither you can access environment variables. As opposed to app.config.js where you can access environment variables like so

```
{
  expo: {
    name: "my-app",
    slug: "my-app-slug",
    extra: {
      customVariable: process.env.CUSTOM_VARIABLE
    }
  }
}
```

I.e. that's the difference between the dynamic and static configurations.

Comment: The question was not what is the difference between static and dynamic configurations, it was what is the difference between app.JSON and app.config.JSON.  Both are static definitions, but why have two naming conventions and which is preferable? That was the question.